# AR9485 wireless card loses ability to connect after hibernation

Tags: wireless, networking, atheros

This has happened twice now, the first time it happened I just reinstalled Ubuntu.  The only things that I've been messing with in terms of networking, have been restarting the `network-manager` service after I resume from hibernate (because it never works right after resume, but restarting the service fixes that), and changing my mac address with `ifconfig wlan0 down && ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 11:22:33:44:55 && ifconfig wlan0 up`.  using `tail | dmesg` returns a bunch of attempts to connect, saying something like

`authenticating ... okay you're connected! now I'm going to just disconnect because I feel like it.  (reason=3).`

Any ideas? If it helps maybe I'll add a picture of the `tail|dmesg` output later.

My wireless drivers are as follows:

- Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
- Hamachi Network Interface
- Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport Adapter
- Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

[Here is a pastebin of some terminal outputs that could help.](http://pastebin.com/e6fzxcwe)

Also, the reddit thread has a few answers, for anyone curious.  It's located [here.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/26zyw4/lost_ability_to_connect_to_wifi_for_the_second/)

It is entirely possible that it's just my school wifi blocking out my laptop, and my home wifi sucks.  Wifi does work at places other than my home and school, however my phone can connect to both places.

[Here is a pastebin of the results of the wireless-info script.](http://pastebin.com/16RDmJC7)

Comment: UbuntuForums have got an experimental script to obtain more information about your wireless connection.  Please can you run this and pastebin the results.  Thanks.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qjc87hzk1z5x6z0/wireless_script

Answer (score 1):

This issue looks remarkably similar to this [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221294) thread.

In the module parameters section of the [Wireless Info script](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qjc87hzk1z5x6z0/wireless_script) reveals you are using a `wapf=0` parameter.

The UF thread recommends you use `wapf=1` instead.

To do this you use the following in a terminal:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

To reverse:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558)